# How to upload folder from local to GCP bucket using python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I am following this link and getting some error:

[How to upload folder on Google Cloud Storage using Python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599503/how-to-upload-folder-on-google-cloud-storage-using-python-api)

I have saved model in container environment and from there I want to copy to GCP bucket.

Here is my code:

```
storage_client = storage.Client(project='*****')
def upload_local_directory_to_gcs(local_path, bucket, gcs_path):

   bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket)

    assert os.path.isdir(local_path)
    for local_file in glob.glob(local_path + '/**'):
        
        print(local_file)


        
        print("this is bucket",bucket)
        blob = bucket.blob(gcs_path)
        print("here")
        blob.upload_from_filename(local_file)
        print("done")

path="/pythonPackage/trainer/model_mlm_demo" #this is local absolute path where my folder is. Folder name is **model_mlm_demo**
buc="py*****" #this is my GCP bucket address
gcs="model_mlm_demo2/" #this is the new folder that I want to store files in GCP

upload_local_directory_to_gcs(local_path=path, bucket=buc, gcs_path=gcs)
```

`/pythonPackage/trainer/model_mlm_demo` has 3 files in it config, model.bin and arguments.bin`

**ERROR**

The codes doesn't throw any error, but there is no files uploaded in GCP bucket. It just creates empty folder.

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your bucket and empty folder from GCP Storage?

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra uploaded

Comment: I have posted an answer below. Please check and confirm.

Answer (score 1):

What I can see the error is, you don't need to pass the `gs://` as the bucket parameter. Actually, here is an example you may need to check out,

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python

```py
def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    # The ID of your GCS bucket
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # The path to your file to upload
    # source_file_name = "local/path/to/file"
    # The ID of your GCS object
    # destination_blob_name = "storage-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

    print(
        "File {} uploaded to {}.".format(
            source_file_name, destination_blob_name
        )
    )
```

Comment: Even after I remove gs, I cannot see any files in folder. Strange. It's almost same code I have written above?

Comment: @MAC I noticed you pas the directory to the `upload_from_filename` but you should pass file paths one by one, but not the directory path.

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced your issue and the below code snippet works fine. I have updated the code based on folders and names you have mentioned in the question. Let me know if you have any issues.

```
import os
import glob
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client(project='')

def upload_local_directory_to_gcs(local_path, bucket, gcs_path):

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket)

    assert os.path.isdir(local_path)
    for local_file in glob.glob(local_path + '/**'):

        print(local_file)

        print("this is bucket", bucket)
        filename=local_file.split('/')[-1]
        blob = bucket.blob(gcs_path+filename)
        print("here")
        blob.upload_from_filename(local_file)
        print("done")


# this is local absolute path where my folder is. Folder name is **model_mlm_demo**
path = "/pythonPackage/trainer/model_mlm_demo"
buc = "py*****"  # this is my GCP bucket address
gcs = "model_mlm_demo2/"  # this is the new folder that I want to store files in GCP

upload_local_directory_to_gcs(local_path=path, bucket=buc, gcs_path=gcs)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the [gcsfs](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library which seems to be also about better interfaces

You could copy an entire directory into a gcs location like this:

```
def upload_to_gcs(src_dir: str, gcs_dst: str):
    fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem()
    fs.put(src_dir, gcs_dst, recursive=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way using subprocess to upload model artefacts in GCP bucket.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('gsutil cp -r source_folder_in_local gs://*****/folder_name', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

If gsutil is not installed. You can install using this link:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install